# How to mock CONSTANT at Module-imported level

Tags: python, python-unittest, python-module, python-mock

I have some classes that declared like below:

Processor.py

```
from package.moduleA.moduleB.LogService import LogService
class Processor:
  ....
```

LogService.py

```
LOG_PATH = "log/file.txt"
file_handler =TimedRotatingFileHandler(LOG_PATH)

class LogService:
 ....
```

test.py (test for Processor)

```
from package.moduleA.moduleB.Processor import Processor
class Test(unittest.TestCase):
  def test_something(self):
    .....
```

The problem is when I tried to run the unit test by the command below, I got the error because the LOG_PATH is incorrect.

As I know so far, before the test run, it will import the *Processor* module. The *Processor* module is depended on the *LogService* module. Thus, it will scan the LOG_PATH and init the TimedRotatingFileHandler as well. It's happened at module-import level.

> coverage run -m unittest discover

Are there anyway to mock / change the value for LOG_PATH?

Comment: How is LOG_PATH incorrect and how do you want to mock it?

Comment: did you solve this? I'm having the same problem.